# Why does accessing a data member of a forward declared class give me a read access violation?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, in the first class, 'DrawGraphics' I am trying to access a member variable from a class that I have forward declared 'MainComponent'. However, this leads to a read access violation.

This is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Unique_ptr_base<juce::Slider::Pimpl,std::default_delete<juce::Slider::Pimpl> >::_Myptr(...) returned 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

I'm using the JUCE framework by the way, the exception occurs here:

```
    _NODISCARD pointer operator->() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // return pointer to class object
        return (this->_Myptr()); // <-- this is the exception breakpoint
        }
```

what you see below is only about 20% of the actual code but I'm going to try and only include the relevant parts of each file so as not to drown you in questionably written code.

**DrawGraphics.h**

```
class MainComponent;

class DrawGraphics : public Component
{
public :

void clock();

private:

    MainComponent* mainComponent;
};
```

**DrawGraphics.cpp**

```
#include "DrawGraphics.h"
#include "MainComponent.h"

void DrawGraphics::clock()
{

    double sliderOutput = mainComponent->ampSlider.getValue();

    // THIS ^ CAUSES THE ERROR

    DBG("Slider output is : " << sliderOutput);

}
```

**MainComponent.h**

```
class MainComponent : public Component,
                      public Slider::Listener
{
public:
    Slider ampSlider;
    void sliderValueChanged(Slider* slider) override;

private:
    DrawGraphics drawGraphics;
};
```

**MainComponent.cpp**

```
void MainComponent::sliderDragStarted(Slider* slider)
{
    if (slider == &ampSlider)
    {
        drawGraphics.clock();
    }
}
```

I was hoping to simply be able to access the data stream that is produced from ampSlider. Apologies in advance if I failed to include parts of the code that are actually relevant to the issue.

...

EDIT:
Ok so my problem was I hadn't intialised mainComponent. I did this by changing
`MainComponent* mainComponent;` to `MainComponent* mainComponent{};` in DrawGraphics.h

and then in DrawGraphics.cpp I created an object of mainComponent by simply adding `mainComponent = new MainComponent;` at the start of DrawGraphics::clock()

It seemed as though when trying to get a value of ampSlider, I was referering to an empty, unitialised object.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Do you initialize `mainComponent`?

Comment: Has `mainComponent` been assigned a value?

Comment: MainComponent is a pointer, are you sure it is initialized and has an actual value during runtime?

Comment: do you ever assign something to `mainComponent` ? If you do, it is not in the code you show. Btw the forward declaration is a red herring, because in the cpp you do include the header and the full declaration is available (otherwise you couldn't access the member at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainComponent seems to be uninitialized, change to:

```
MainComponent* mainComponent{};
```

Then, before using, check for null:

```
if (!mainComponent) {
  return;
}
//do stuff with mainComponent
```

Should solve the issue.

Comment: I initialised as you said like this:

```MainComponent* mainComponent{};```

and checked for null but it is in fact null despite initialising as you suggested.

Comment: @crypton it is not null **despite** initializing it but it is null **because** of the initialization. If you want to make the pointer point  to an object you need to create an object

Comment: @user463035818 OK, I think I'm almost on board.. but what object should it point to in order to obtain the slider value? Or how would I create an object that would allow me to do so?

Comment: you can try with `new MainComponent{}`

Comment: @darune perfect! that did the job. thanks very much. I'll mark as solved and amend my original post to show what I did.

Comment: mainComponent should probably not be a pointer, but the object itself. (and if you really want it to be a pointer, use smart pointer instead of raw owning pointer).